# CUDA-why it cannot printf the information in cuda code?

Tags: cuda

I am a beginner for cuda. I wrote a test code for testing GPU device. my gpu  model is k80.

There are 8 gpu cards in one node.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>

#define N 10000

__global__ void add(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
  int tid = blockIdx.x;
  if (tid < N)
   c[tid] = a[tid] + b[tid];
}

int main()
{
 int a[N], b[N], c[N];
 int *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;
 cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, N * sizeof(int));
 cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, N * sizeof(int));
 cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, N * sizeof(int));

 for (int i = 0;i < N;i++)
 {
  a[i] = -i;
  b[i] = i*i;
 }

 cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
 cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

 add << <N, 1 >> > (dev_a, dev_b, dev_c);
 cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

for (int i = 0;i < N;i++)
{
    printf("%d + %d = %d\\n", a[i], b[i], c[i]);
}

   cudaFree(dev_a);
   cudaFree(dev_b);
   cudaFree(dev_c);

   return 0;
}
```

When i compile the code:

```
 nvcc gputest.cu  -o gputest
```

I got errors :

```
 gputest.cu(38): error: identifier "printf" is undefined
 1 error detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_000059a6_00000000-4_gputest.cpp4.ii".
```

I think printf is a function in iostream file, but i have already included the iostream. I don't know why?

Answer (score 2):

Add:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
```

and it will compile is OK.

`printf` is a function [defined in the C standard library cstdio](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/), so inclusion of `stdio.h` makes sense here.  Different compilers may have different behavior here, but in the case of `nvcc` this is generally the right way to do it.

(It's not valid to assume in all cases that inclusion of `iostream` will satisfy the reference here.)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24925176)

Comment: @AksenP: This is a perfectly valid answer and your review is incorrect

Comment: @talonmies, it's your opinion. This answer looks like `who's the first one who will find what I'm forget to add for making this function to be workable?`. This answer hasn't any explanation also.

Comment: Note it is a self answer

Comment: now it has some explanation.